# Parse Error creating a second router outlet in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a simple button with the Routerlink but I am getting this error:

> Parser Error: Unexpected token '}' at column 37 in [[{outlets: {side-mod: ['table-list']}}]]

What I am trying to do is create a second outlet for the router. So I have this in my routing component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, outlet:'header' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet:'header'},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, outlet:'header' },  
  { path: 'user', component: BoardUserComponent, outlet:'header' },

  { path: 'table-list', component: TableListComponent, outlet:'side-mod'},


  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

So, the "index" has this kind of buttons at the header:

```
 <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[{outlets: {header: ['user']}}]" skipLocationChange="true" replaceUrl="false">Home </a>
```

And the router at the bottom to show the different pages:

```
<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
```

So when the user press the header button to see the 'user' page, a new component appears with buttons that uses another 'outlet', but the error appears:

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light" [routerLink]="[{outlets: {side-mod: ['table-list']}}]">Tables</a>
```

I tried a lot of things to fix it like changing it to this code, but the same error appears:

```
[routerLink]="['', { outlets: { side-mod: ['table-list'] } }]"
```

Comment: could you make a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove - from side-mod to sideMod or side_mod

Comment: Yes, the problem was this. Now I have a different problem, is not showing the component but not having that error.

Comment: Can you tell a bit much what are you trying to achieve with this second router outlet ?

Comment: Yes, It is a component with navigation inside. But the router is trying to navigate doing like user/sideMod.  So it's not working. Basically I have a header with buttons ( user, home, etc). The button user is a routerLink that shows a component. This component has a navigation system too, similar to the header, so I need the router too. Hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried ?

```
[routerLink]="['' ,{outlets:{'side-mod':'table-list'}}]
```

the problem might come from the `-` character that is not recognised as a being a valid key character , wrapped around `""`this should work, I've also got rid of the `[]` array.